# How to set Cookie from server side api in graphql mutation in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

I tried developing a server side API. I am using GraphQL and want to set a cookie from the server side, but when i try to set the cookie using `HttpServletResponse` it gives me a `NullPointerException`?

Here is my Response View class:

```java
package org.jembi.appstore.service.graphql.api.response.view;

public class ResponseView {

    private int code;
    private String message;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And here I am setting the cookie:

```java
@GraphQLMutation(name="login")
public ResponseView login(@GraphQLArgument(name="msisdn") String msisdn, @GraphQLArgument(name="password")String password, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ResponseView responseView = new ResponseView();
    User user = new User();


    System.out.println(msisdn.length());
    Cookie cookie = null;
    if(msisdn.length()==10) {
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setMsisdn(msisdn);

        int code = userDao.getUser(user);
        responseView.setCode(code);
        if(code==100) {
            responseView.setMessage("User Logged In Successfully");

            cookie = new Cookie("token", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            //responseView.doPost(req, resp);
            int hour = 3600000;
            int exp = 14 * 24 * hour; //2 weeks

            cookie.setMaxAge(exp);
            //cookie.setPath("/");
            cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            //responseView.setCookie(cookie);

        }   
        else 
            responseView.setMessage("Invalid credentials");

    }else {
        responseView.setCode(400);
        responseView.setMessage("Bad Request");
    }
    return  responseView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems you're using GraphQL SPQR. I can't tell if you're using SPQR Spring Starter as well or not, so I'll just have to assume you are, since your question mentions nothing.

In recent versions, an instance of `DefaultGlobalContext<NativeWebRequest>` is automatically provided as GraphQL context, so it can be inject by `@GraphQLRootContext`:

```
@GraphQLMutation(name="login")
public ResponseView login(
     @GraphQLArgument(name="msisdn") String msisdn, 
     @GraphQLArgument(name="password")String password,
     @GraphQLRootContext DefaultGlobalContext<NativeWebRequest> context) {

    HttpServletResponse response = context.getNativeRequest().getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class);
    ... //do what you need to with the raw HTTP response
}
```

If you want to provide a different context, register a custom bean of `ServletContextFactory` type.

In case you're not using SPQR Spring Starter, you'll have to ensure you provide the applicable context yourself via `ExecutionInput`:

```
ExecutionInput input = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
        .query(graphQLRequest.getQuery())
        .operationName(graphQLRequest.getOperationName())
        .variables(graphQLRequest.getVariables())
        .context(response) //HttpServletResponse or whatever you need
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  **graphql-java-kickstart / graphql-java-servlet**

Assuming that you can get the

```
DataFetchingEnvironment env
```

then you can do this:

```
GraphQLServletContext context = env.getContext();
context.getHttpServletResponse().addCookie(cookie);
```